# How can I track down dyld: Symbol not found error?

Tags: ios, dyld, symbol-not-found

I have an app which has iOS 6.1 as the minimum deployment target. In my project I'm using a couple of 3rd party libraries. When I try to run my app using Xcode 6.1.1, on an iOS 6.1.3 device, I'm getting this error and the app cannot continue running:

> dyld: Symbol not found:
>   _AVAudioSessionMediaServicesWereLostNotification   Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/8CCB531B-1749-4484-8B6B-AF6221CB409D/ProductName.app/ProductName
>   Expected in:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation  in
>   /var/mobile/Applications/8CCB531B-1749-4484-8B6B-AF6221CB409D/ProductName.app/ProductName

OK, AVAudioSessionMediaServicesWereLostNotification is available after iOS 7.0 and that's the problem. What I need to know is which 3rd party library of mine is causing this error. Do you know how I can track this error message and learn which library is responsible of this?

Comment: You can use the nm and grep from a terminal session (i.e. `nm <library-name> | grep _AVAudioSessionMediaServicesWereLostNotification`).

Comment: It says "dyld" in the error message. nm wouldn't catch this, would it?

Comment: I'm suspecting a framework and I tried to do what you're suggesting: I cd'ed to the framework's directory and on the terminal I ran nm x.framework | grep _AVAudioSessionMediaServicesWereLostNotification command. I got an error saying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/nm: can't map file: x.framework (Invalid argument). Was this what you were suggesting? And thanks for your help!

Comment: A framework is a folder, not a file. Go into the framework folder an run `nm` against the binary inside the folder.

Comment: Oh yes, of course. This did the trick guys, the terminal put out a line that says "U _AVAudioSessionMediaServicesWereLostNotification". You can put this as an answer and I can accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @aslisabanci can you please tell how you solve this, I am facing it for Moya sdk saying, dyld: Symbol not found: _$s4Moya10TargetTypeP010validationC0AA010ValidationC0OvgTq
  Referenced from: /Users/webwerks/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx_vendor-cgtedtytezmfykcveauikltppxjk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxxlitesdk.framework/xxxlitesdk
  Expected in: /Users/webwerks/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D4369393-4AD0-41CA-A131-6695BDBDBC11/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C1473A9B-FFD7-4F8D-A8AD-815E60FAF7DA/xxx_vendor.app/Frameworks/Moya.framework/Moya